# Using colors inside a tailbox of the Linux "dialog" tool

Tags: linux, colors, dialog, tail

I have written a tool consisting of Bash scripts. This tool echos log messages with colorized strings into a log file like this

```
echo -e "\e[1;33mHello \e[1;34mWorld\e[0m" >> /tmp/foobar.log
```

And when I `tail` the log file, it returns the line with the colorized strings. That works as a charm.

Now, what I need is a way how I can colorize output of the **tailbox** component of the `dialog` tool (well, if this is possible at all). The command I'm using:

```
dialog --tailbox /tmp/foobar.log 100 200
```

The **tailbox** does not recognize the color sequences from the `echo` command (prints the raw line like `^[[1;33mHello...` instead).

However, `dialog` has the `--colors` argument which can be used to set the text colors inside the dialogs, for example inside an **infobox**:

```
dialog --colors --infobox "\Z3Hello \Z4World" 3 20
```

(Works fine.)

So, I also tried that using the **tailbox**:

```
dialog --colors --tailbox /tmp/foobar.log 100 200
```

And added lines like that:

```
echo "\Z3Hello \Z4World" >> /tmp/foobar.log
```

As well as:

```
echo "\\Z3Hello \\Z4World" >> /tmp/foobar.log
```

With the same result: The **tailbox** also ignores these sequences and prints the raw line.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What does this issue have to do with bash?

Comment: @Jdamian You are right, just removed the tag